# Convert an expression that does not involve matrix into an expression involving matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, regression

I have a MS in Statistics and I did well in MS-level course in statistical inference. I had no problem with the MS course because the course used mostly calculus to conduct proof, and I have a good understanding in calculus.
However when I look at a PhD course in statistical inference, it scares me quite a bit because it is heavily loaded on linear algebra. Although I did very well in my undergraduate linear algebra courses, I am not fully comfortable with the linear algebra operations. To be more specific, I get scared when everything is expressed in terms of matrices, and when I look at the matrix equation I do not know how to interpret it.

For example, my textbook says that in Generalized Linear Model,
[image]

[image]

and I don't get and can't see how the equation expressed under sigma is equivalent to 
(matrix X transpose) * (matrix V) * (matrix X). My question is:

**Is there any trick that I can use when trying to convert an expression that does not involve matrix into an expression involving matrix?** I just cannot do this quickly. For instance, how can the expression
$x_ix_i^T$ inside sigma be obtained by computing $X^TX$ ??? Shouldn't it be that 
$X^TX$ will make expression inside sigma to involve $x_i^Tx_i$ instead? 
Thank you,

Comment: What is $x_i$ here? I think that it is the $i-th$ row of the matrix $X$ but looked at as a column vector, thus you get $x_i x_i^T$ which is a $p\times p$ matrix (I'm assuming $X$ is a $n\times p$ matrix of predictors).

Answer (score 0):

Remember - writing $Ax = b$ is a compact way of writing the corresponding equations - each row represents an equation.

Let me expand on this. Consider the system

\begin{align*}
3x + 5y &= -10 \\
2x - 3y &= -1.
\end{align*}

This can be compactly written as

$$\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 5 \\
2 & -3 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x  \\
y  \\
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -10 \\ -1 \\ \end{pmatrix}$$

as the matrix multiplication yields the above scalar equations. Again, each row of the coefficient matrix represents a part of the equation in the system.

Comment: how can the expression
$x_ix_i^T$ inside sigma be obtained by computing $X^TX$ ??? Shouldn't it be that 
$X^TX$ will make expression inside sigma to involve $x_i^Tx_i$ instead? 
Thank you,

Comment: Depends on what the matrix $X$ is. If it's the usual design matrix that I'm used to, I can provide more details for this - otherwise I can't say more. I should also say that matrix representations really clean up a lot of stuff in linear models - it could help to review this.